# Aggregate count and sum in SQL

Tags: sql

I have 3 SQL table

TABLE 1:

| VIN | model | color |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 83498 | Ford Fusion | yellow |
| 233244 | Renault Car | Red |
| 2343 | Renault Car | Red |

TABLE 2: Translation VIN to License plate

| VIN | License_plate |
| --- | --- |
| 83498 | ABC123 |
| 233244 | EDF567 |
| 2343 | YEL898 |

Table 3: Table showing license plate at Spots

| License_plate | Spot |
| --- | --- |
| ABC123 | 1 |
| EDF567 | 1 |
| YEL898 | 2 |
| YEL898 | 4 |
| YEL898 | 5 |
| EDF567 | 2 |

How can I write a SQL query to see if a model number has been spotted at multiple spots ?

Answer (score 0):

In SQL we can use `GROUP BY` to create sets of results to aggregate the values in each set, when you want to limit the *Groups* with an aggregate function we use `HAVING` to express the desired filter condition.

The first step is to construct a query that resolves the `Model` that was sighted at each `Spot`:

```
SELECT t3.license_plate, t1.model, t3.Spot
FROM table3 t3 
INNER JOIN table2 t2 ON t3.license_plate = t2.license_plate 
INNER JOIN table1 t1 ON t2.vin = t1.vin
```

It is always a good idea to inspect this raw result set first, to ensure that your joins are expressed correctly, this will result in the following:

| license_plate | model | Spot |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ABC123 | Ford Fusion | 1 |
| EDF567 | Renault Car | 1 |
| YEL898 | Renault Car | 2 |
| YEL898 | Renault Car | 4 |
| YEL898 | Renault Car | 5 |
| EDF567 | Renault Car | 2 |

From that result set, we expect to find that `Renault Car` is *spotted* multiple times, we can use `GROUP BY` and the `COUNT` function to calculate the number of `spot` values that each `model` was sighted at:

```
SELECT t1.model, COUNT(t3.Spot) as [Spots]
FROM table3 t3 
INNER JOIN table2 t2 ON t3.license_plate = t2.license_plate 
INNER JOIN table1 t1 ON t2.vin = t1.vin
GROUP BY t1.model
```

This returns:

| model | Spots |
| --- | --- |
| Ford Fusion | 1 |
| Renault Car | 5 |

Finally, we can use the HAVING clause to filter the results based on the result of the `COUNT()` aggregate function:
*multiple can be expressed in SQL as "more than 1"*

```
SELECT t1.model
FROM table3 t3 
INNER JOIN table2 t2 ON t3.license_plate = t2.license_plate 
INNER JOIN table1 t1 ON t2.vin = t1.vin
GROUP BY t1.model
HAVING COUNT(Spot) > 1
```

| model |
| --- |
| Renault Car |

You can see this in action here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/26ed4/2
*In the fiddle the number of spots is also included in the output.*

Answer (score -1):

You can use aggregation -- after joining the tables together of course:

```
select t1.model
from table3 t3 join
     table2 t2
     on t3.license_plate = t2.license_plate join
     table1 t1
     on t2.vin = t1.vin
group by t1.model
having min(spot) <> max(spot);
```

Comment: This example is not compilable, the column names do not match OPs request and Using MIN() <> MAX() is not good advice at all, `Spot` represents a discrete location (assumed from the language used in the post) OP wants to know the models that are seen in different spots so we use `COUNT()` to ah count the number of spots the cars have been seen at.

Comment: You provided a low quality, code only answer without any documentation, OP asking for something so basic clearly needs the additional advice. your initial post clearly misinterpreted OP and you still advise comparing MIN() <> MAX() which is very misleading. As someone with such high rep you need to be more careful, people will take your answers as gospel, as a community we expect much more from you.